# layoutx / layouty values

Tags: javafx-2

I have a problem to find out the correct layoutx / layouty values for shapes. Please have a look at this example:

```
package test;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;

public class TestLinePosition
    extends Application
{
  private Line line;

  private Scene getScene()
  {
    Group group = new Group();

    line = new Line(10, 10, 60, 10);

    group.getChildren().add(line);

    Scene scene = new Scene(group, 640, 480);

    return scene;
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
  {
    stage.setScene(getScene());
    stage.show();
    System.out.println("x: " + line.getLayoutX() + ", y: " + line.getLayoutY());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Application.launch(args);
  }
}
```

If I run this program the line seems to be positioned as expected starting at 10, 10. However the layoutx and layouty values are 0, 0.

Can anybody give me an explanation for this behaviour and / or tell me how to find out the actual position?

Thank you,
Roger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mix starting positions for painting with layout positions.
When adding a node to a Group you set it's layout position on the x-axis by calling `setLayoutX(xValue)`. So calling `getLayoutX()` returns the expected value.

Your example (reworked):

```
package test;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestLinePosition extends Application {

    private Line line;        

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }


    private Scene getScene() {
        Group group = new Group();

        //layout position is x:0 and y:0
        //painting starts at x:10 and y:10
        line = new Line(10, 10, 60, 10); 
        //x position for layout
        line.setLayoutX(100);
        //y position for layout
        line.setLayoutY(100);

        group.getChildren().add(line);

        Scene scene = new Scene(group, 640, 480);

        return scene;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setScene(getScene());
        stage.show();
        System.out.println("x: " + line.getLayoutX() + ", y: " + line.getLayoutY());
        System.out.println("start x: " + line.getStartX() + ", start y: " + line.getStartY());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your line has coordinates (10, 10) - (60, 10) in its local coordinates. `LayoutX` and `LayoutY` can translate this coordinates further inside Group's local coordinates.

- If you want to know Line Layout Bounds inside Group you can use `line.getLayoutBounds().getMinX()`.
- If you want to know Line Position inside scene you could also use `line.localToScene(10, 10)` method.